# PHP how to merge array in foreach loop

Tags: php

How do i merge all `$related_array` in the foreach loop into 1 array not multidimesional.

```
 $get_categories = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT related FROM wp_pato_category_related WHERE slug IN ('$categories')");

                foreach($get_categories as $array) {
                        $related_array = unserialize($array->related);


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array using [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://uk.php.net/spl)

So in your code, flatten $related_array with `RecursiveArrayIterator`

```
$related_flat = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($related_array));
```